# laravel ffmpeg setAdditionalParameters not adding filters when using exportForHLS

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am trying to add additional filters using the setAdditionalParameters method to the bitrate using Laravel Ffmpeg. When I add the additional filters it does not show when used in combination with exportForHLS. It does however work when using the export method.
When using exportForHLS the addFilter method adds a complex filter and not a simple filter. Any idea how to achieve this or is this a bug inside the package.

```
  public function convert(File $file, Movie $movie)
{
    try {
        $additionalParameters = ['-preset:v', 'ultrafast'];

        //  convert video to multiple bitrates
        $higBitrateFormat = (new X264('copy'))
            ->setAudioChannels(2)
            ->setKiloBitrate(3000)
            ->setAdditionalParameters($additionalParameters);

        $mediaOpener = FFMpeg::fromDisk($file->disk)
            ->open($file->path)
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->setSegmentLength(4)
            ->setKeyFrameInterval(48)
            ->addFormat($higBitrateFormat)
            ->toDisk('streamable_videos')
            ->save($file->uuid . '.m3u8');

        $attr = ['converted_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()];
        $this->movieRepositoryInterface->update($movie->id, $attr);
        return $mediaOpener;
    } catch (EncodingException $exception) {
        $attr = ['conversion_failed' => 1];
        $this->movieRepositoryInterface->update($movie->id, $attr);
        Log::error('encoding failed.', [$exception->getErrorOutput()]);
        throw new CustomEncodingException($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getCode());
    }
}
```

Here is the ffmpeg output:

> -y -threads 12 -i /home/vagrant/code/streaming-api/storage/framework/testing/disks/public/videos/Am1t18C8NnnOlxPCVIx3OiEMzcaXhhEpReDBpBaW.png -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 3000k -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 4 -hls_segment_filename /home/vagrant/code/streaming-api/storage/framework/testing/disks/streamable_videos/9703f521-ec4b-428f-b756-b08946e726b8_0_3000_%05d.ts -master_pl_name temporary_segment_playlist_0.m3u8 -acodec copy -b:a 128k -ac 2 /home/vagrant/code/streaming-api/storage/framework/testing/disks/streamable_videos/9703f521-ec4b-428f-b756-b08946e726b8_0_3000.m3u8

Comment: post your code in your question, not images.

Comment: Very new to stack overflow will do. Thanks